# An graph algorithm

Tags: algorithm

There is a algorithm question which I really can't figure it out. The question may use Dijkstra algorithm.

There is a network of n computers that you will hack to take
control. Initially, you have already hacked computer c0
. There are m connections between
computers, through which you can use to take down an uncontrolled computer from a hacked
one. Each connection is described as a triple (ca
; cb
; t), which means if ca
is hacked, then you
can successfully hack cb at a cost of t minutes.

A large group of your hacker friends join you in hacking (they are as good as you and as
many as the computers in the network). They are all at your command, which means
you can assign them hacking tasks on multiple computers simultaneously. Describe an
ecient algorithm to determine how many minutes you would need to successfully hack
all the computers in the network. State the running time in terms of n,m.

Comment: Smells like homework …

Comment: Seems more related to max-flow

Comment: It is a homework but I have no idea of this problem

Comment: @CBroe No close vote?

Comment: As you have as many hackers as computers on the network and can therefore hack in parallel, the time to hack all the computers is equal to the distance between c0 and the *most distant vertex from c0* (with distance being cost in minutes). To find the most distant vertex, you need to find the distances of all other vertices from c0. This problem is called *single source shortest paths* in directed graphs and there are algorithms which solve it efficiently. As this is homework, I suggest you google "single source shortest paths" and familiarize yourself with the related concepts and algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your computers are labeled as `c_0, c_1, ..., c_{n - 1}`. After you running Dijkstra  the answer you are looking for is `max { d[i] | 0 <= i <= n - 1}` where `d[i]` denotes the minimum distance between `c_0` and `c_i`. This is true because: 1) you at least need time equal to maximum of all those distances in order to hack the most distant computer 2) take a look at the tree we got after applying Dijkstra's algorithm (`c_0` would be the root of that tree). We can apply the following strategy: first we start off hacking all the neighbors of `c_0` and we continue with hacking all computers that have already been hacked. We do this until all the computers have been hacked. We can see that the time needed for this to happen would be equal to maximum depth of the tree (note that the edge of this tree have weight equal to those of the original graph). We can easily see that this is exactly the same number we mentioned before. So the total running time would is equal to Dijkstra's `O(m + nlogn)`